# how to remove images from folder using url src images as id?

Tags: image, codeigniter, textarea, unlink

I have an article and I want to delete the article when the image is in it is also deleted from the storage folder. and I want to delete the image by taking the src url image in the article

this is my article :

```
<p><img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/coba//berkas/news/blog-1560149702190.jpg" alt="1.jpg" /></p>
```

and i want get the image name like this :

```
blog-1560149702190.jpg
```

how to doing that ?

Comment: Do you want image name after deletion?

Comment: use `unlink()` with `absolute path`

Comment: i want get the name of the image from url src image in the article

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: here you would probably need regex or xpath.. however if i were a malicious user i would code in `src="http://localhost/coba/index.php"` and your script (if you got it to work) would delete the main index file of codeigniter. the better solution would be to store images per article in a separate folder for that article. then store that path in the database alongside the article. then when you delete that article, you simply delete the associated folder according to the path from the database. this is safer, and less clunky.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the image name then delete it.

```
$image_url = "http://localhost/coba//berkas/news/blog-1560149702190.jpg";
$image_name = substr( strrchr($url, '/'), 1 );

// Check that the is indeed a file and that that file is an image type.
if(is_file($image_name) && strpos(mime_content_type($image_name), 'image/') === 0 ) {
    unlink($image_name);
}
```

As other people have said, deleting images like this poses security risks. In the code above i only check that the source URL is actually a file of an image type, however, you need to perform additional checks to make sure that the image you are deleting is indeed associated with the article and that the article has been deleted first.